# How do you minimize repeating yourself when working with UITableViewControllers

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, dry

When I work with UITableViewControllers - especially when using NSFetchedResultsController - I find myself repeating a lot of base functionality on every controller. Which I hate. I'd much rather love to write these methods once and keep it all neat and tidy.

So I was wondering: What do you guys do to not repeat yourself writing UIViewControllers. How do you [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) up your code. Inheritance, protocols, whatever.

Thanks! Looking forward to your answers.

(Since this question doesn't have a definitive answer, I will accept the one I find the best.
Is that the way to do it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own controllers with the basic functionality and then subclass and reuse them. Check the CoreDataTableViewController class that was built for the Stanford iPhone Application Development course -> http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/node/167

Comment: I like this. The first time I tried it, I couldn't make it work, but I started over and I've got something going.

Answer (score 1):

One technique is to subclass your own subclass.  This, modularizes and isolates the differences nicely, however it generates a lot of classes and files, which some find harder to read.

Another technique, which you can use when you want to create a bunch of almost identical controllers with just slight differences, is to give one class a "type" parameter or instance variable.  Set the controller's type when you init a controller, and use the controller's type in "if" or switch statements (etc.) to select between slight differences in controller behaviors at run-time.  This can help keep all the differences more compactly located in source code.

Answer (score 0):

I made this new Core Data wrapper for iOS in Swift - https://github.com/tadija/AERecord

It has Swift version of CoreDataTableViewController, and CoreDataCollectionViewController also.

Beside that you can use it to setup Core Data stack like this:

```
AERecord.setupCoreDataStack()
```

Access context for current thread like this:

```
AERecord.defaultContext
```

Save context like this:

```
AERecord.saveContext()
```

Create fetch requests like this:

```
NSManagedObject.create()

NSManagedObject.firstOrCreateWithAttribute("city", value: "Belgrade")

NSManagedObject.deleteAll()

let predicate = ...
NSManagedObject.firstWithPredicate(predicate)

NSManagedObject.allWithAttribute("year", value: 1984)
```

And much more... I hope it will be useful for someone.